# CarrierWave with plupload direct to s3 - how to avoid redundant download/upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have recently finished setting up plupload to upload files directly to S3. This is done using S3s [posting](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) method in combination with plupload.

After the upload is finished, I queue a delayed job that loads up a model and uses the remote_[uploader]_url method of CarrierWave to assign that uploaded resource to the model. I would like to use CarrierWave because of the simplicity of managing multiple versions. Here is my job (slightly edited, I realize I could use send_later for this simple example):

```
class MediaJob < Struct.new(:medium)
  def perform
    medium.process_file
    medium.save
  end
end
```

Here is the process_file method:

```
def process_file
  self.remote_file_url = s3_original_url
end
```

The result is that the file ends up moving in and out of S3 three times:

1) Uploaded to S3 with plupload

2) Downloaded by CarrierWave for processing

3) Re-uploaded by CarrierWave when the model is saved

This is all well and good for a small file but gets very expensive when dealing with larger files. There must be a way to eliminate #3. I don't want CarrierWave to upload the original file when it saves since the original file is already there. I do want the versions to be uploaded though.

Comment: I just cant understand your question What processing do you want to do with carrierwave . and I guess you dont have to have to set the remote s3 url yourself carrierwave automatically does it . Check carrierwave documentation

Comment: I want carrierwave to generate a number of versions. Plupload is simply uploading the raw original. I bypass carrierwave on the first upload because the upload needs to go direct to s3 and I don't want the user to wait while it creates the different versions.

Comment: @retailvolved There is a way to generate version in carrierwave and also { pre-process }            [http://virenegi.blogspot.in/2012/04/process-process-in-carrierwave.html] the uploaded file I you want too but since your requirement is not to let the user wait both of them wont work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have found a solution. Thanks to the contributors for getting it started. I want to make sure credit is given where it is due but the answer was a bit more involved than what was proposed.

Here is what worked....

1) After plupload finishes uploading to S3, I assigned the file attribute (my mounted CarrierWave uploader) to the returned key from S3. This is accomplished in plupload by using the FileUploaded event to post the response to another action:

```
init : {
    FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
        $.post('#{media_path}', {s3_response: info.response});
    }
}
```

2) The action picks up that response and assigns the file attribute(or whatever the name of your mounted uploader is) via a method on the model:

```
def create
  med = Medium.new_from_s3_response(params[:s3_response])
end

def self.new_from_s3_response(response)
  med = Medium.new

  # Grab filename from response use libxml-ruby gem
  xml = XML::Parser.string(response).parse
  node = xml.find_first('//PostResponse/Key')
  med['file'] = node.content
  med.save

  # Queue up a job to have the file downloaded and processed
  # Note that I am using Mongoid so the handy serialization by DelayedJob doesn't work
  Delayed::Job.enqueue MediaJob.new(med.id)
end
```

3) The job fires and calls process_file which downloads the original and creates/uploads the various versions. Note that the original does not get uploaded. Mission accomplished!

```
class MediaJob < Struct.new(:medium_id)
  def perform
    medium = Medium.find(medium_id)
    medium.process_file

  end
end  

def process_file
  # Download from S3
  file.cache_stored_file!
  # Convert to sanitized file for creating versions
  file.retrieve_from_cache!(file.cache_name)

  # Loop through versions and create them....
  file.versions.values.each do |uploader|
    uploader.store!
  end
end
```

I got the code for creating the versions from a wiki entry on the [CarrierWave GitHub](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog) page.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `update_attribute` it should skip callbacks. I don't know how carrierwave works internally but that's what I would try:

```
def process_file
  update_attribute(:remote_file_url, s3_original_url)
end
```

You can then skip calling `save`.

An alternative is to change `save` to `save(:validate => false)`.

EDIT: You can use `skip_callback` to skip validations http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_callback

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll give it a shot and then see if calling recreate_versions! after updating that attribute will trigger the version creation.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I actually need the call to remote_file_url= so that the image gets downloaded for creation of the versions. The trick is preventing it from re-uploading somehow when saved since the uploader thinks it has not been uploaded yet.

Comment: Closer but digging into the source code of carrierwave I can see that the action of uploading is triggered by the after_save callback. save(:validate => false) will still trigger callbacks.

Comment: @retailevolved `save(:validate => false)` doesnot skip callbacks it just skip validation there is no such syntax in Rails3+ to skip callbacks other then hacky method like `update_column` `update_attribute` and `update_all`

Comment: You're right. So you can still call `remote_file_url=` to download the file and then call `update_attribute`? Or use `skip_callback`

Answer (score 0):

Perhap You could try something like ( I also done something like this for CSV file stored in s3)

```
1. Download the file to your local directory first 

2. Process the the image (create your version) 

3. And then Upload the file to s3 using fog gem separately 

4. update the remote_url  from the url from the fog gem
```

This will cut done your step from 3 to one

You can check  Fog [documentation](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/README.rdoc) for the fetching the s3 url

Hope this help

Comment: @retailevolved `Step 2,3,4` could be moved in some background processing like `resque` or `delayed_job`

Comment: @retailevolved I guess this libary too does the same thing but under the nicety of the gem https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

Comment: I am using background processing for everything but the initial upload but I am dealing with hi-res images so I want to avoid the upload / download / upload process for that original hi-res file. The user experience is already where I need it to be. Regarding proposed solution, do you know how to update the remote_url without triggering carrierwave to upload the file again? This is where I am stuck.

Comment: @retailvolved If you closer look at carrierwave method the section of uploading is done in callbacks to avoid the callback you could use `update_column` on the database field name . something like update_column('avatar',new_name) update the database field and check `.url` method on it something like `@user.avatar.url` I hope this should work